# AEM Form - Where could I configure the types of attachment field?

Tags: forms, aem, aem-6

I have an issue when I created an AEM form in 6.5 version.
And it returned this "The attached file(s) types p66.jpg are not supported. Check these file(s) and resubmit the form" when I submitted form with an attached file.

Could anyone help me this one? Just want to know where I can configure the types for this field.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Normaly it should work by default. May be there some things wrong in your code.

Comment: I just created a simple form. It works for me on 6.2 but didn't work on 6.5

Comment: No idea from me. In my career I worked with different versions of AEM and I have never had this trouble.

Comment: Can you provide html code?

Answer (score 0):

We figured out that, 6.5 works with image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png instead of .jpg,.jpeg,.png

It fixed my issue.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Where did you modify this setting?